# Paypal: Reauthorization - Authorisation Expiry Date is Not Showing Correct

Tags: php, paypal, authorization

[Paypal: Unable to Reauthorize Authorized Payment Error : An internal service error occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583789/paypal-unable-to-reauthorize-authorized-payment-error-an-internal-service-err)

Above code works automatically without any changes.

1] For Original Authorisation Id: XXXXXX Expiry Date: 27 May 2017

URL : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_history-details-from-hub&id=XXXXXXXXXXX

2] Reauthorization Id of Above One: XXXXXXXXX Expiry Date: 27 May 2017

URL : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_history-details-from-hub&id=XXXXXX it's still showing Authorisation Expiry Date : 27 May 2017 11:31 SST

Using API : https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/XXXXX it gives **valid_until : 2017-06-02T07:17:45Z**

So where above **valid_until** date is going to display? I'm not able to find new date in Sandbox